# multiple condition sorting in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a sort which looks like

`sort=score_dx desc, date_dt desc`.

The problem is if there is a tie on first sort then the second sort applies to the whole record not only to the already sorted subsets.

for ex:

this is what I have from above sort

```
score_dx   date_dt 
0.1       2015/10/24

0.1       2015/10/23

0.9       2015/10/20

0.9       2015/10/19
```

what I want is

```
score_dx   date_dt 
0.9      2015/10/20

0.9      2015/10/19

0.1      2015/10/24

0.1      2015/10/23
```

The first sort result should not change and then the second sort whouls apply to within the subset.

How to do this in Solr?

Comment: The example query you've given should give you the result you want. You don't have multiple sort= entries in your query string? What is the type of score_dx and date_dt? And are 0.9 from one field and 2015/10/19 from another field? (score vs date, the one field with / between them made me unsure). If 0.9 vs 0.9 were first, I'd suspect IEEE 754 inaccuracies for a floating point number, but 0.1 being sorted first is suspect.

Comment: @MatsLindh `score_dx` is `TrieLongField` and `date_dt` is a `TrieDateField`. yes they are from different fields. I am not getting what is expected. If there are same score values then the date_dt sort takes over and even if there is a low score row with recent date, that comes on the top

Answer (score 1):

Since `score_dx` is a `TrieLongField`, the value will be cast to an integer (long is an integer with a broader range than what int has, 64 bits vs 32 bits), meaning that all the values you've indexed are, in fact, identical. Sorting by them will then give a order which seem random between them, and the only thing actually applying a sort will be the second criteria.

Change the field to a `TrieDoubleField` and reindex your content, and sort should work as you expect.

The reason why you're seeing 0.9 is that this is the *stored* value of the field, and not the actual value used for searching.